# How to access with Pyramid the data generated by Plone and persisted on ZODB?

Tags: python, plone, pyramid, zodb

I have a file Data.fs that contains data persisted by Plone on ZODB. Only the standard content types of Plone were used (eg. ATNewsItem, ATLink, ATFile, ...). I would like to use Pyramid (www.pylonshq.org) to access this data (only read, no write) and can recover, for example, the title of an NewsItem or Link. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the information you'll need to have the original classes available for import; the pickles can only be loaded into the original class structures.

I am not sure that will work all that well; there are a lot of assumptions and dependencies that may clash with the Pyramid framework, or cannot be satisfied without the Zope framework being available.

An alternative would be to create *new* classes that you make available through the original import locations that let you at least just read the contained data, but that could amount to a major effort.

If you need read-only access you may want to look into a different approach though; use some [means to export the data](http://developer.plone.org/content/importexport.html) to, say, a SQL server. That will be easier to handle in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Martijn. I'll evaluate the problem on another perspective.